# How to send data to function with conditionals parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function:

```
export const changeNotes = (userId, note, isStay)
```

I want to use to change a note, and sometimes I want to use it to change the value of `isStay`.

```
const handleOnChange = async e => {
      await changeNotes(user.id,null ,true) // await changeNotes(user.id,10 ,null)
}
```

How do I send different cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object as an argument to your changeNote function, and then use function argument destructuring to use properties from it. This way, order doesn't matter and only the values you send will be used (anything you don't pass will be undefined).

```
export const changeNotes = ({ userId, note, isStay }) => {
  if (note) { // undefined
  }

  if (isStay) { // true
    // do something
  }
}

const handleOnChange = async e => {
  await changeNotes({
    userId: user.id,
    isStay: true
  })

}
```